# Match HttpGet object which is being created internally in method under the test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to mock a behavior by returning different `CloseableHttpResponse` objects based on urls. For `URL1` I want to give `302` response and for `url2` I want to give `200` ok response. Method under this test takes `url` as input and create a `HttpGet` request object internally and do something with `httpresponse` object. But I am unable to match the `HttpGet` argument. Is there any way I can test this method. P.S. `httpClient` is also a mock object. The following code is not working as the expectation are not able to mock new `HttpGet(Url)`.

```
   CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
    when(httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(URL1))).thenReturn(httpResponse);
    when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(new BasicStatusLine(new ProtocolVersion("1.1",0,0),HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY,""));
    when(httpResponse.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.LOCATION)).thenReturn( new Header[]{new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, URL2)});

    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse1 = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
    when(httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(URL2))).thenReturn(httpResponse1);
    when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(new BasicStatusLine(new ProtocolVersion("1.1",0,0),HttpStatus.SC_OK,""));
    when(httpResponse.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH)).thenReturn( new Header[]{new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, "0")});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you unable to `mock` or `match` the HttpGet object?  Your question isn't entirely clear, but I think you're looking for this: https://mrtnrbrts.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/custom-matchers-with-mockito/

Comment: Hi Taylor Thanks. Match will be correct word. edited :). Can you elaborate more, how  link you have provided solve my problem.

Comment: I would seriously propose to move these kinds of tests to WireMock.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Good point.  It's a little unclear what the test is in fact testing, as we see only a snippet, but using a mock http server rather than mocking up huge swathes of apache http client is certainly worth considering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a custom argument **matcher**.

So something like this in your test class:

```
static class HttpGetMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<HttpGet> {

    private final URL expected;

    //Match by URL
    public HttpGetMatcher(URL expected) {
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object actual) {
        // could improve with null checks
        return ((HttpGet) actual).getURI().equals(expected);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText(expected == null ? null : expected.toString());
    }
}

private static HttpGet aHttpGetWithUriMatching(URI expected){
    return argThat(new HttpGetMatcher(expected));
}
```

The above could also reside in some test utils class if you need in multiple test classes.  In that case, the method `aHttpGetWithUriMatching` would then need to be public.

And then in your test method:

```
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
when(httpClient.execute(aHttpGetWithUriMatching(URL1))).thenReturn(httpResponse);
when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(new BasicStatusLine(new ProtocolVersion("1.1",0,0),HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY,""));
when(httpResponse.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.LOCATION)).thenReturn( new Header[]{new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, URL2)});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works correctly with one matcher. Though I got stuck in second issue. When I try to set expectation for URL2 it start giving me null pointer exception. Resolved on this page    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846837/using-multiple-argumentmatchers-on-the-same-mock?rq=1